# Как с помощью webpack переместить index.html в папку dist?

Tags: webpack, webpack4

Сейчас у меня index.html просто лежит в src, но мне надо чтобы когда я прописал npm run build он у меня собрался в папку dist. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'js/main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        static: {
            directory: './dist',
            watch: true
        }

    }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "3dglo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start": "webpack serve --mode=development --open"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.58.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для этого загрузчик html (например, html-loader) - https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/ и в объекте правил (rules) добавите настройки для этого плагина, и также в обьекте плагины (plugins) добавите этот новый плагин